# How to handle offset in tigergraph using built in list vertices endpoint

Tags: tigergraph, gsql

I want to handle offset using builtin endpoint -List vertices in tigergraph . I do not see any parameter called offset . Should we write custom GSQL query ,just for supporting offset?

Here is the builtin endpoint link , which Iam referring.
https://docs.tigergraph.com/tigergraph-server/current/api/built-in-endpoints#_list_vertices

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. Unfortunately the current built-in list vertices endpoint doesn't include an offset flag https://docs.tigergraph.com/tigergraph-server/current/api/built-in-endpoints#_list_vertices

**List Vertices Parameters:**

`count_only` Takes a boolean value. If the value is true, the results field will only contain the count of how many vertices were selected. Default is false.

`select` Attributes of the selected vertices to return. The parameter takes a list, which is a string of comma-separated values, and will only return the attributes that are provided.

`filter` Conditions used to filter the returned vertices. The parameter takes a list of conditions, which is a string of comma-separated values. If any filter conditions are provided, the endpoint will only return the vertices that satisfy the conditions. Six comparison operators are supported for this parameter: =, !=, >, >=, < and <=. If the value on the right side of an operator is a string literal, it should be enclosed in double-quotes.

`limit` Integer value that specifies the total number of vertices to return

`sort` Attributes to sort the results by. The parameter takes a list, which is a string of comma-separated values, and will sort the returned vertices based on the attributes provided in the list in order. Add "-" in front of the attribute to sort in descending order.

`timeout` Integer that specifies the number of seconds after which the query will time out. If the parameter is set to 0 or isn’t provided, the system-wide endpoint timeout setting is applied.